# Convert string to date object without changing time in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, timezone

I need help figuring out how to convert `String` to `Date` object without date changes due to timezone.

For example from http get request I receive `2020-07-14T15:27:39Z` I need this converted to `Date` object in order to calculate time(substract this date from current date).

But whenever I convert this `String` to `Date`, it always uses my local time zone and adds some hours to it. How do I convert string to `Date` ignoring my timezone as the `String` is already using the correct timezone?

`Date.parse` `new Date()` all of them convert using local timezone and in my case add 3 hours. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the date in template as UTC, you can use the [Date Pipe of Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

You can keep your date as local date, there's no problem. For example in your ts file:

```js
   myDate = new Date('2020-07-14T15:27:39Z');
   // For me it shows Tue Jul 14 2020 12:27:37 GMT-0300, for you it will be another date
```

on the template:

```html
  <p>Date in local time: {{myDate | date }}</p>
  <p>Date in UTC: {{myDate | date : 'mediumDate' : '+0000' }}</p>
```